# Add row Id in Django data table

Tags: django, django-datatable

I am using django datatable the data that come from server has the following format:

```
[ ['id_value','data col1','data col2',...]
   .
   .
   .]
```

I am  try to make id to every row as follow:

```
'rowId': 1,
```

**but it doesn't work**

my html code:

```
<table id="mainDataTable" class="table table-responsive-md table-{{ documentvals.table_type }}">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% for field in list_fields %}
                                <th> {{ field }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            {% for field in list_fields %}
                                <th> {{ field }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

Also, my js code is:

```
let _columns= [
    {% for field in list_fields %}
        { "data": '{{ field }}' },
        {% endfor %}
]

$('#mainDataTable').DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "columns": _columns,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "pageLength": pag,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": mainUrl,
        },
        'rowId': 1,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        destroy: true,
    });
```

I did not want to edit Django datatable library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think you are trying to give something like a S.No. to your table in the form of `rowId` for whatever purpose.

Something like `enumerate` in python might be needed to achieve this, In this case you can use forloop counters in django templating, available in multiple variants as follows
[image]

Just for reference, Here is how you can use this in your `_columns` variables `for` loop of js file

```
let _columns= [
    {% for field in list_fields %}
        { "data": '{{ field }}', "rowId": '{{forloop.counter}}' },
    {% endfor %}
]
```

Similarly, it can be used in your table as well.

I highly suggest you to have a look a [official django templating forloop documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)